# директива 404 в .htaccess ломает сессии. Почему?

Tags: php, .htaccess, сессия

Раньше такого никогда не наблюдал.
Но на одном проекты, по сессиям определяется размер объекта.
Если в .htaccess прописать ErrorDocument 404 /404.php - PHP сессии ломаются. Почему?
И именно эта директива влияет на сессии.

Comment: потому что 404.пхп у нас  небось ничего не инкулдит, а сам `session_start` не вызывает

Comment: @teran, т.е. если я вас правильно понял. В 404.php тоже нужно "пробрасывать" сессии ?
Там всё (стандартное для проекта) инклюдит и даже session_start() присутствует.
Сами переменные из сессий, естественно не пробрасывал через 404.php, считаю это неправильным ходом.